# how can i solve this problem that appears while i run "buildozer android debug" on the terminal

Tags: android

Cloning into `'python-for-android'`...

> Error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>
> fatal: early EOF
>
> fatal: index-pack failed

Command failed: `git clone -b master --single-branch https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git python-for-android`

Buildozer failed to execute the last command

The error might be hidden in the log above this error:

> Please read the full log, and search for it before
>   raising an issue with buildozer itself.
>
> In case of a bug report, please add a full log with `log_level = 2`

Comment: how is this related to R?

Comment: I think you are missing the correct tags - maybe python